# INSERT into table including foreign keys to related tables

Tags: database, ms-access, select, insert, multiple-databases

Please if someone could help,

I have three tables: 1. Clients; 2 Accounts; 3. Transactions ...

I want to get ClientID by ClientName and also AccountID by AccountName and then insert those ID`s to Transactions and some other values for some other fields that are known ...

Clients

```
ClientID | ClientName | ...
```

Accounts

```
AccountID | AccountName | ...
```

Transactions

```
TransID | Account ID | ClientID | Value | Tax | Total
```

how can i do it ... i tried many many forms of the insert statement but it didnt work

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Transactions (AccountID, ClientID, Value) Values 
(SELECT AccountID WHERE AccountName = 'Some Name' 
 FROM Accounts, SELECT ClientID WHERE ClientName = 'Some Name' FROM Clients, 30.00 )
```

Comment: Cab you show us something you tried?

Comment: The last one i tried is:
INSERT INTO Transactions (AccountID, ClientID, Value)
Values (SELECT AccountID WHERE AccountName = 'Some Name' FROM Accounts, SELECT ClientID WHERE ClientName = 'Some Name' FROM Clients, 30.00  )

Comment: `SELECT ClientID WHERE ClientName = 'Some Name' FROM Clients, 30.00` wont this return a string? did u try keeping it in braces?

Comment: It should return an int because ClientID is declared as int ...

Answer (score 1):

`Value` is a reserved word in MS Access.

I think you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Transactions ( AccountID, ClientID, [Value] )
SELECT Accounts.AccountID, Clients.ClientID, 30.00 AS Expr1
FROM Accounts, Clients
WHERE (((Clients.ClientName)='Jimmy') AND ((Accounts.AccountName)='Mark'));
```

You'll need to rewrite the SQL to properly fit your tables/table names possibly but this worked for me.

You should also make sure `Value` is a `Double` data type, not a long integer. (which is the default for a Number field)

Comment: I get SQL Execution ERROR

Comment: @ShpetimHaxhiu That doesn't tell me much. If you copied exactly what I wrote, you'll probably need to change table names and possibly field names to match your database.

Comment: @ShpetimHaxhiu I don't. I just tried OverMind's query and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Okay here is what i did ... i removed [Value] and also 30.00 AS Expr1 just to test ... but it doesnt work it says SQL Execution ERROR... Value in my case is another column that i want to feed

Comment: My suggestion is to remove Clients or Accounts piece from the query and attempt it then. e.g `INSERT INTO Transactions ( AccountID ) SELECT Accounts.AccountID FROM Accounts WHERE Accounts.AccountName='Mark'`